# Adventureworks creation scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been fighting for a long time trying to get one of the myriad of adventureworks databases I've downloaded installed and running in SqlServer 2012 Express. As per usual with SQL Server, the error message is not helpful at all (can't find .ldb blah blah). I would really like to run some of the samples out there for things like MVC Scaffolding and Entity framework.

Does anyone know where I might get some creation scripts for the database so I can just create it without Attaching the mdf?

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that if you scroll down a bit on the page http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211
There are some scripts to download. I downloaded one and it failed when I ran it but at least now I can step thru and see why.

Answer (score 0):

> As per usual with SQL Server, the error message is not helpful at all

Er, my experience is quite the opposite.  The error message typically tells you exactly what you did wrong.  "Can't find .ldb file," for example, says, "I can't find the transaction log."  Well, is the file there or isn't it?

Try downloading the databases from [here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587).  I'm not sure why MS has that other project location that only has the DB files without logs.  That page is basically useless except for the scripts.